# Nightwatch ERROR: Unable to locate element: using: css selector

Tags: javascript, automation, nightwatch.js

I am a newbie to nightwatch and javascript and for the life of me I am getting stuck at some weird places. I am trying to do a simple test which just clicks on three different tab menu items one at a time. When I run the code I get an **ERROR: Unable to locate element: "@Performing_AF" using: css selector.**

If I go ahead and use the css selector directly opposed to using elements the code works. Can someone guide me as to where I am going wrong?

The URL I am testing is: https://www.nypl.org/

Here is **/pages/homepage.js**

```
    var elements = {
     searchbutton: '.nyplHomepageApp button[name = "Search Button"]',
     Authortalksconversations: '.titleTabs #tab-0',
     Exibitions: '.titleTabs #tab-1',
     Performing_AF: '.titleTabs #tab-2',
     Other_Events: '.titleTabs #tab-3',
     DonateButton: '#donateButton',
     Shop: '#shopTopLink',
     loadicon: '.dcom-loader',
     searchboxbutton: 'button[type="submit"]',
     inputsearch: '.desktopSearch-form-inputBox #desktopSearch-form-searchInput'

   };

   var quicksearch = {
     go: function()
     {
             this
                     .waitForElementVisible('body', 6000)
                     .api.pause(2000)
                     .click('@Exibitions')
                     .pause(2000)
                     .click('@Other_Events')
                     .pause(2000)
                     .click('@Performing_AF')

     }

  };

 module.exports = {
     elements,
     commands: [quicksearch]
 };
```

And here is tests/homepagetest.js

```
     module.exports = {

'Q': function(browser) {
    var goto = browser.page.homepage();
    goto.go;


    //browser.end();
        }

   }
```

Comment: It's something to do with all the pauses in your `go` function. I removed them all and the test ran fine. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do with this test but a typical test would perform some action and then assert that you got an expected result. Just clicking on all the tabs isn't very useful. It doesn't tell you anything except that the tabs were present on the page. You could do that without clicking on them by using `browser.assert.visible('@someElement');`

Comment: I removed the pause and it works but I want to slow down the test, after each click. Is there a way to do this? Is there an alternative to pause?

Comment: There is `waitForElementVisible` and `waitForElementPresent` that you can use. So you would click on a tab, wait for some element in that tab to be visible, and then move on to the next one. You can keep it the way you originally had it by adding three variables at the top of your function and doing something like this instead of using the `@elementName` syntax. `var exhibitons = this.elements.Exhibitions.selector` and then `.click(exhibitions)`

Comment: alright gotcha, so best practice, avoid overusing .pause()

Comment: Yes. Honestly, I avoid it at all costs if I can. It makes the tests very flaky and unreliable.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry about that. I am trying to dabble in some automation and theres not much night watch js online tutorials that speak on best practices and what not. Do you have a blog? Also can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't have a blog. I'm too busy for that and yeah I'll add it in a few minutes. There is a really good course on automation best practices on Pluralsight. It's where I got started and then the rest I've learned over the last few years of writing tests and building frameworks. Just be patient. It will all click eventually.

Comment: lol okay, and thank you for that info I will get started on it. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments above, if you remove all the pauses from the test it will work. I'm not exactly sure the reasons behind that. It would be better to use `waitForElementVisible` or `waitForElementPresent` whenever possible. `pause()` will make your tests flaky and unreliable.

The way you would use these is

1. click on a tab
2. wait for some element on that tab to be visible / present
3. click on the next tab and repeat

If you really would like to keep the pauses you can get it to work by adding a few variables at the top of your `go` function and using those variables instead of the `@someElement` syntax.

```
go: function() {
      var exibitions = this.elements.Exibitions.selector;
      var otherEvents = this.elements.Other_Events.selector;
      var performingAf = this.elements.Performing_AF.selector;

      this
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 6000)
        .api.pause(2000)
        .click(exibitions)
        .pause(2000)
        .click(otherEvents)
        .pause(2000)
        .click(performingAf)
}
```

Comment: wow ! that's a no brainer and testament that I don't have a brain :D thanks for the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me
`ul.titleTabs > li#tab-2`

Your css selector also works out for me. What is the error that you're facing?

Comment: Basically I created a element **@Exibition**  to store the css selector **.titleTabs #tab-1'**. My error is when I use the element '@Exibition'. I get an error message  ERROR: Unable to locate element: "@Exibition"